# Can anyone explain this solution (contractive function, interval, first derivative related)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

> We are trying to find a positive null $x \geq 0$ of $$f(x) =
> \sqrt{x+1}+\frac{\text{sin}(x)}{10}-2$$
>
> Choose $X=\left[0,8\right]$. For $x \in X$ we have that
>   $$\frac{1}{15}= \frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{10} \leq f'(x) =
> \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}+\frac{\text{cos}(x)}{10}\leq
> \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{10} = \frac{3}{5}$$
>
> (YOU COULD STOP READING HERE BECAUSE I'M RATHER INTERESTING IN JUST UNDERSTANDING THE STEPS TILL HERE.)
>
> Now try to find a $\beta$ such that $\text{sup} \left|1+\beta
> f'(x)\right|<1$, i.e.
>
> $-2 < \beta f'(x) <0 \text{ }\forall  x \in M$. Because of the
>   inequality above, we have that $$-\frac{10}{3} < \beta <0$$
>
> We can thus set $\beta = -3$ and $\phi(x) = x-3f(x) =
> 6+x-3\sqrt{x+1}-\frac{3}{10}\text{sin}(x)$. Thus
>   $\left|\phi'(x)\right| \leq \frac{4}{5}= 0.8$
>
> So, we have a contractive mapping.
>
> [... further things that need to be shown so we satisfy all conditions (that there even exists a null). I leave them out to not make this question longer.]

I'm mainly interesting in understanding the beginning where we have $$\frac{1}{15}= \frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{10} \leq f'(x) =
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}+\frac{\text{cos}(x)}{10}\leq
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{10} = \frac{3}{5}$$

Can you tell me how you get that? I understand that in the middle we have the first derivative of $f$. On the right side, we took the beginning of interval zero and put it into the first fraction, so $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{0+1}}= \frac{1}{2}$. Then put zero in the second fraction: $\frac{\text{cos}(0)}{10}=\frac{1}{10}$. This explains why we have $\frac{3}{5}$ on the right side.

But how do you get the left side, especially how you get $-\frac{1}{10}?$ We insert the end of interval on the left, $8$, I think. But why we have $-\frac{1}{10}$ ?

Comment: Hum, $x\in [0,8]$?

Comment: Consider $-1\leq \cos(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$. And consider $2\leq 2\sqrt{x+1}\leq 6$ if $x\in[0,8]$ by using the boundary points $x=0$ and $x=8$. Now you get $\frac16\leq \frac1{2\sqrt{x+1}}\leq \frac12$ for $x\in[0,8]$.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt: Post as an answer? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $-1\leq \cos(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ yields
$$
-\frac1{10}\leq \frac{\cos(x)}{10}\leq \frac1{10}.
$$
And consider that $x\mapsto\sqrt{x+1}$ is monoton increasing. Therefore you get $$
2\leq2\sqrt{x+1}\leq 6
$$
for $x\in[0,8]$ using the boundary points $x=0$ and $x=8$. This yields
$$
\frac16\leq \frac1{2\sqrt{x+1}}\leq \frac12
$$
for $x\in[0,8]$. Together we get
$$
\frac16-\frac1{10}\leq \frac1{2\sqrt{x+1}}+\frac{\cos(x)}{10}\leq \frac12+\frac1{10}
$$
for $x\in[0,8]$.

Comment: I have made another example to try myself. Maybe you can tell me if I did it correctly? We have $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac{sin(x)}{15}\text{ with }[1,9]$$

$1\geq -sin(x)\geq-1$, so we have $\frac{1}{15} \geq -\frac{sin(x)}{15} \geq -\frac{1}{15}$ and if we insert boundary points $x=1$ and $x=9$, we get

$$\frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\geq\frac{1}{6}$$

Altogether, we have that $$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{15}\geq\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac{sin(x)}{15}\geq\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{15}$$

?

Comment: Yes, you translated the arguments correctly. You got it.

Answer (score 3):

As, you rightly calculated $f^{'}(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}} + \frac{cos(x)}{10}$.

Now at the boundary point $x=8$, $$f^{'}(8) = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{cos(8)}{10}$$
Finally as $cos(8)>-1$,(i.e. the step you were looking for) we get 
$$f^{'}(8) \geq \frac{1}{6} - \frac {1}{10} $$